# what order does AudioRecord class of Android store the audio samples in?

Tags: java, android, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

If I call the read() method, as

```
record.read(lin, 0, R_fft);
```

where `lin` is a short array of size 256 and `R_fft` is 8, in what order does the read() function store the audio samples from MIC in? For instanc, is it

```
lin[0] -> oldest sample  
.  
.  
lin[8] -> newest sample
```

or is it the other way round, that is

```
lin[0] -> newest sample  
.  
.  
lin[8] -> oldest sample
```

or do the samples go towards the higher end of the `lin[]` array, that is towards, `lin[248]` to `lin[255]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `read()` is an offset that specifies where in the array you want the samples to be stored. Since you're passing `0` you'll get the samples at the beginning of the array (i.e. at `lin[0..7]`).

The oldest sample will be stored at the lowest address (`lin[0]`), and the latest sample at the highest address (`lin[7]`).